# When creating a new list (from data in two separate source lists) - having difficulty adding source data correctly. (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to add together two lists and create a third list.

My first list does not have values for each list element.

So I only want to create a third list with the summation of list elements in list 1 and 2 if there are values in list one.

This part works okay - However, when I try to add the values together - it doesn't keep the values from list 1 and 2.

*(Please see desired output below for disambiguation)*

Here is the code:

```
z=0
for i, val in enumerate(okay_to_gl):
    if val is not None:
        for x, val2 in enumerate(okay_to_zn):
            if x == i:
                print(val)
                print(val2)
                output_array_1 = val[z]+val2[z]
                z = z + 1
                print(output_array_1)
```

This is the output:

[image]

val = OK, val2=to ZA, so i want output_array[0] = OKto ZA

So the desired output would be:

OK

toZA

OKtoZA ... and so fourth.

SO output_array_1 =(val+val2,val+val2,val+val2) where val and val2 are passed from their values during the enumerate iteration of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can simply be done using the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd']
>>> list2 = ['q', 'w', 'e', None, 'r', 't']
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if not (x is None or y is None)]
['aq', 'bw', 'dr']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing two lines because you have two print calls:

```
print(val)
print(val2)
```

just replace them with a single print call:

```
print(val + val2)
```

Moreover, you're needlessly wasting a **lot** of cycles with the choice of coding:

```
    for x, val2 in enumerate(okay_to_zn):
        if x == i:
```

Just say instead `val2 = okay_to_zn[i]` -- Python lists **are** indexable!

Comment: As far as the print - that is just a check

I'll take your point on the cycling to bring the data together though - I'm sure there is a more efficient way using index-able lists - but I don't quite understand the logic right now.

Answer (score 0):

Generally fro merging arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5]
c = a+b
print c
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

In your case a way to achieve this would be:

```
list1 = ["ok","not_ok","fine",None,"",89]
list2 = ["B","7","train",3]

N=min(len(list1),len(list2))

new_list = []
for iterator in range(N):
    val1 = list1[iterator]
    val2 = list2[iterator]
    if val1 is not None and val2 is not None :
        new_list.append(val1 + val2)

print new_list
```

Output:

```
['okB', 'not_ok7', 'finetrain']
```

If you care only for `list1` not to be equal to 0 you may add:

```
for iterator in range(N,len(list1)):
    val1 = list1[iterator]
    if val1 is not None:
        new_list.append(val1)
print new_list
```

Comment: Ah - but I would want output to be [14,25,3] in that case.

Comment: Also this would override the new array each iteration - I want list3 =([val1+val2]@[0],[val1+val2]@[1],[val1+val2]@[2])

Comment: The 'Another way' was the only way it worked for me - thanks a ton! Saved me a huge headache, thanks for sharing your knowledge!